# Random FASTA file generator

Tags: python, bioinformatics

This is my code to generate a FASTA file containing multiple records with randomized DNA sequences with distinct length. I am looking for feedback on how to write this script better.

```
"""
    Generates random fasta file.
    Number of records and length of each record is given by user.
"""
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from random import choices

DNA = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
prob = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25] #probability of each base
number_of_records = 100 #number of fasta records
length_of_records = 180 #length of dna sequnece

with open("outputfile.fasta", "w") as output_handle:
    for i in range(number_of_records):
        dna_seq = choices(DNA, prob, k=length_of_records)
        dna_seq = ''.join(dna_seq)
        #Create a SeqRecord object
        record = SeqRecord(Seq(dna_seq),
            id="Chowder_"+str(i+1),
            name="Chow-Chow",
            description="random sequence")
        SeqIO.write(record, output_handle, "fasta")
```

Answer (score 3):

`DNA` should be immutable - a tuple `()`.

`prob` should go away, and you can just omit it from the `choices` call. The default non-weighted behaviour will be the same as what you've written.

`do_thing();  # Do thing` comments like `#Create a SeqRecord object` are less helpful than having no comment at all, so you can just drop it.

`"Chowder_"+str(i+1)` is more easily written as `f"Chowder_{i+1}"`.

It's not a great idea to re-assign a different type to the same variable `dna_seq`; just use a different name.